# Dart: The argument type 'E' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'E'

Tags: dart, casting, extension-methods

The error makes 0 sense.

here is the implementation:

```dart
extension MyList<E> on List<E> {
    List<E> returnList<E>() {
      final List<E> output = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        final el = elementAt(i);

        output.add(el);
      }

      return output;
    }
}
```

although `el`'s type is `E` and `output` returns a list of `E`, each`E` is considered different, because when I cast `el` to `E`, like `final el = elementAt(i) as E;`, it works perfectly.

what is going on and why am I having this error?

Comment: Your `returnList` method takes a type parameter `E` even though it's already parameterized on a different `E` via `MyList<E>`.   Change `returnList<E>` to just `returnList`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks, that solved it!